# Sum of numerous String Values Using Loop

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdMVG.png)I have a String named as Price. I take values of Price from the firebase database. I want to make sum of these String Values and make a total Price.  The Value of Price increases automatically according to the child in the database. For example the values are 100, 70, 50, 20, 40 etc. And it will increase accordingly.

I think there should be a loop to make the sum of all these values to make it total price.

This is what i have done so far.

```
 int pos = 0;                                     
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 if (jsonObject.has(Integer.toString(pos))) {
 } else {                                       
     try {                                               
         jsonObject.put(Integer.toString(pos),Price);                                         
     } catch (JSONException e) {                                           
         e.printStackTrace();                                         
     }                                    
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
     try {                                  
         String itemInArray = jsonObj.getString(String.valueOf(i));
         int Sum =  0;
         int totalPrice = sum + itemInArray;

  } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
```

But The code is not working. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to fix layout of your code, but it's quite obvious it wouldn't even compile - you are missing catch block and closing curly brace. Also if-else looks suspicious.

Comment: I assume, first of all, you should do `jsonObject.put` within `if` block, not `else`

Comment: @Ilia Nedoluzhko updated my answer please have a look

Comment: You need to fill jspnObject in loop by increasing pos variable, fill from values of firebase. You dont increase pos, and your jsonObject always has one element.

Comment: You should convert `itemInArray` to an `int`.

Comment: @Ansar Ozden  i have array but it is showing separately like the picture i have attached above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's isolate the part of the code where is the problem of *Summing numerous String Values Using Loop*.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
     try {                                  
       String itemInArray = jsonObj.getString(String.valueOf(i));
       int Sum =  0;
       int totalPrice = sum + itemInArray;

     } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

Every time you loop through this code you **reassign** the value of 0 to `Sum` and as a result `totalPrice`s value is always 0 plus the itemInArray (which, another problem, is a String and cannot be directly added to an integer).

Assuming everything else is right and `itemInArray` holds a numeric value here is the code to find the total price:

```java
try{
       int sum = 0; // you don't need the totalPrice variable, they will hold the same result 
       for (int i=0;i<jsonObj.length(); i++) {
        String itemInArray = jsonObj.getString(String.valueOf(i));
        int itemPrice = Integer.ParseInt(itemInArray);
        sum = sum + itemPrice;
      }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now the `sum` is not redefined in every loop, it keeps its value from the previous loop and it adds itself and `itemPrice` in the next iteration.

Comment: still getting the same result. The String are coming separately as mentioned in the picture above @Themelis

Comment: Yes but in your code you never add them, you just print them. That's why the final price is for example `100` and then falls to `70`, as shown in your picture. There is no addition happening. Put the `sum` out of the loop and add the values inside the loop.

Comment: int pos = 0;JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
if (jsonObject.has(Integer.toString(pos))) {  } else {
try {
 jsonObject.put(Integer.toString(pos),Price);
 } catch (JSONException e)     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 } int sum = 0;  try{
 for (int i=0;i<jsonObject.length(); i++) {
String itemInArray = jsonObject.getString(String.valueOf(i)); int itemPrice = Integer.parseInt(itemInArray);
sum = sum + itemPrice;
 }
 }catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
                                           }    Log.d("app","total addition" +sum);

Comment: i have put it outside of loop same results